# Looking for rails/ruby method that returns order number of object in a relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am trying to get the order number of a record in a table.  I have a model called Survey.  There are 4 surveys in the database.  If I run `Survey.all` I get

```
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation 
    [#<Survey id: 138, presentation_id: 300, created_at: "2015-08-24 20:51:25", updated_at: "2015-08-24 20:57:07", current_question_id: 417, complete: true, survey_taker_name: "">, 
     #<Survey id: 136, presentation_id: 297, created_at: "2015-08-24 20:25:55", updated_at: "2015-08-24 20:27:36", current_question_id: 392, complete: true, survey_taker_name: "try 1">, 
     #<Survey id: 141, presentation_id: 302, created_at: "2015-08-25 17:48:38", updated_at: "2015-08-25 17:49:31", current_question_id: 417, complete: true, survey_taker_name: "">
    ]>
```

I am looking for a way to find what the order is of a specific record.  For example, let's say there was a method called `record`.  If I called:

```
Survey.find(141).record
```

I would get back `3`.  If I call

```
Survey.find(136).record
```

I would get back 2.

Is there any method like that in Rails?

Comment: What DBMS you are using? MySql/Postgresql ?

Comment: postgresql and active_Record

Comment: Why? The results will be ordered by arbitrary criteria depending on how you generated it. This seems brittle and prone to breakage--what's the usecase?

Answer (score 1):

```
Survey.all.map(&:id).index(141) + 1
```

It should show back 3.

```
Survey.all.map(&:id).index(136) + 1
```

It should show back 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch any item ordered in an array by its order by calling the following:

```
Survey.all[number]
```

With 0 being the first item in the collection:

```
Survey.all[0] # first item
Survey.all[1] # second item
Survey.all[2] # third item
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I'm trying to do.  I'm looking for a method that acts on a specific survey object IE Survey.last.  I need to be able to get the number from an object.  The method you wrote only works if I already know a number.

Comment: I see, the challenge here is that the only reason your order isn't following the ranking of ID's must be due to some default_scope acting on the collection to order it in another way.  You're going to need a method to iterate against your collection.  I don't advise this since your collection order will change all the time but it could be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like :

```
@surveys = Survey.select("row_number() OVER(ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS row_num, *")
```

Now, you can do `@surveys.first.row_num` like that.

Example:

```
2.2.1 :002 > a = Account.select("row_number() OVER(ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS row_num, id, email").limit(4)
  Account Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  row_number() OVER(ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS row_num, id, email FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."deleted_at" IS NULL LIMIT 4
2.2.1 :004 > a.first.row_num
 => 1
2.2.1 :005 > a.last.row_num
 => 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't advise you ever do this, but a really inefficient way to achieve this could be done by:

```
Survey.find(141).record # => 3

def record
   Survey.all.each_with_index.map{|object, index| index if object == self}.reject{|o| o.nil?}.first
end
```

Again this is extremely inefficient and as others have said you should not need to be in a position retrieve a collection by its order.  Default scopes and other things threaten to change the order of your collection as generated within Rails constantly, so if you're actually basing your code off of this please relook at your problem.